# LinearLayout Sobre Outro LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Possuo um layout no Android Studio que gostaria que ficasse sobre outro layout, mas não consigo faze-lo de nenhum modo.
Gostaria que ficasse por cima, pois ele é um menu que aparece quando alguém pressiona o botão trocar imagem.

Layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ViewController.ConfiguracaoViewController"
android:background="#FFF"
android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/voltar"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/voltar"
                android:id="@+id/voltar_btn"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:onClick="Voltar"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/configuracao"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:paddingStart="0dp"
                android:paddingEnd="100dp"
                />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include layout="@layout/menu_anexo"/>
    </io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout>





    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/usuario_image"
            android:src="@drawable/muscleman"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/nome_do_usuario"
            android:id="@+id/nome_usuario_text"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textColor="#000"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sincronizar"
        android:id="@+id/sincronizar_btn"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#22BB5B"
        android:onClick="Sincronizar"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/trocar_senha"
        android:id="@+id/trocar_senha_btn"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#22BB5B"
        android:onClick="TrocarSenha"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/trocar_fofo"
        android:id="@+id/trocar_foto"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#22BB5B"
        android:onClick="TrocarFoto"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/politica_privacidade"
        android:id="@+id/politica_privacidade_btn"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#22BB5B"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sair"
        android:id="@+id/sair_btn"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="#22BB5B"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Como o Design se comporta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou com RelativeLayout? O LinearLayout força que os objetos se agrupem vertical ou horizontalmente, não deixando ficar um sob o outro, com o Relative talvez você consiga.

Comment: O que quer não será um [Dialog](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível inserir um `LinearLayout` sobre outro `LinearLayout` usando `RelativeLayout`. O [`RelativeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) é um *layout* que organiza seus componentes de forma relativa e é um dos *Layout* mais utilizados no **Android**. A posição de cada um dos componentes pode ser especificada de acordo com a relação do elemento "irmão" (tal como para a esquerda, de ou abaixo de outro ponto de vista).

> Relative Layout : Organiza os elementos em relação a outro ou do pai

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Exemplo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp" />

  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### Detalhes

- [Relative Layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)
- [Layouts Android](http://fabrica.ms.senac.br/2013/06/layouts-android/)

Comment: Você tem razão quando diz que o `RelativeLayout` "é um layout que organiza seus componentes de forma relativa" e que "A posição de cada um dos componentes pode ser especificada de acordo com a relação do elemento "irmão"", no entanto o seu exemplo não utiliza nenhum dos atributos de posicionamento relativo. Assim, se substituir `RelativeLayout` por `FrameLayout` o resultado é o mesmo.

Comment: @ramaral não utilizo mesmo nenhum atributo, e por este mesmo motivo o primeiro `LinearLayout` ficará sobreposto ao segundo `LinearLayout`, que é exatamente a solução da pergunta. Mas você também tem razão ao dizer que o `FrameLayout` resulta a mesma coisa. Pensando assim, talvez, eu digo talvez seja uma solução mais viável utilizar `FrameLayout`. Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Não conhecia o RelativeLayout ainda, muito útil pelo visto. Muito obrigado pelo auxilio.

Answer (score 0):

use **setVisibility** você deixa visível ou não o layout que você quer mostrar para o usuário dependendo da ação dele.

[setVisibility](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int))